# Angular 5 + AspNetCore + SpaServices + cshtml Can this be done?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, server-side-rendering, angular-universal, asp-net-core-spa-services

This is a two part question...

1) About Angular 5/6 capabilities with Angular Universal and Server Side Rendering.

2) About Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices and its' support for cshtml pages/injecting pre-rendered razor views into Angular.

[image: Use Angular 5 or 6 with Angular Universal for Server Side Rendering Calling cshtml pages??]

**The Goal**

- Merge both Angular and Asp.Net Core into one project (Not only for API use but also for server-side HTML rendering)
- **NOT** use the existing Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaTemplates Angular starter template, since it adds some extra complexity I don't need.
- Utilize the strengths of Asp.Net Core Razor for partial view rendering & manipulation, then send the rendered HTML back to the Angular client
- Angular Client should be able to inject the rendered HTML from the server, then continue DOM manipulation, Binding etc.

**My Progress**

I've successfully created a basic Asp.Net Core project then manually integrated Angular.

**The steps are:**

- Create Asp.Net core project, then use the angular-cli to create a new project in the same directory "**ng new MyAngularApp --minimal**"
- Manually copy the all the files from the "src" folder from the generated MyAngularApp into an Asp.Net Core new folder "ClientApp"
- Then copy the json config files (angular-cli, package & tsconfig) into the root of your Asp.Net Project.

[image: Angular 5 merging config files with asp.net core]

Best Reference I found how to do this was a Pluralsight Tutorial "**Building a Web App with ASP.NET Core, MVC, Entity Framework Core, Bootstrap, and Angular" by Shawn Wildermuth** - https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/aspnetcore-mvc-efcore-bootstrap-angular-web/table-of-contents  (Check out the chapter on Client-side Development with Angular) - for the record I have no affiliation with Pluralsight or Shawn

**The Problem/Question**

I understand using Node.js as a back-end with Angular Universal, but I think in the Asp.Net Core world, there is a perfectly valid case for rendering html via Razor Page.

- **Question:** Can I use  Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices (https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices) to call a cshtml page or call the server url path, that will then render on the server then inject the HTML via the SpaService into the Angular framework.

**Here's an example of the Angular Component**
[image]

Comment: I don't think Angular's compilation model would even allow for this.

Comment: I tried something similar, but with creating viewModel in .net core controller and binding that viewModel to an angular template, but still no luck.. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49413398/pass-razor-model-to-angular-5-component